# Problema con llave foránea en Entity Framework uno a muchos

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estoy teniendo unos problemas de llave foránea, resulta que estoy realizando una revisión a un sistema viejo en el cual se añade una nueva tabla, y al hacerlo, surge lo siguiente.

Resumiendo, tengo las siguientes 3 clases.

```
public class StepUp
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]    
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }    
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accesorio_x_Trafos> Accesorios { get; set; }
    //Muchas otras propiedades..
}

public class Transformador 
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accesorio_x_Trafos> Accesorio_x_Trafos { get; set; }
    //Muchas otras propiedades..
}

public class Accesorio_x_Trafos
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string CodigoAccesorio { get; set; }        
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }       
    public int? Cantidad { get; set; }    
}
```

El asunto, es que tanto `StepUp` como `Transformador` tienen una relación 1-* con `Accesorio_x_Trafos`.

Al realizar la migración, la base de datos se crea correctamente (se añaden las FK)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*(Ignorar la FK Accesorios que es una de las propiedades que removí para no tener tanto código)*

El asunto, es que cuando intento, tanto modificar un objeto de tipo `Transformador` (lo hago de la siguiente manera)

```
//Obtengo un trafo cualquiera
var transformador = mContext.Transformador.First();
//Cargo datos de ejemplo:
transformador.Accesorio_x_Trafos = new List<Accesorio_x_Trafos>
{
    new Accesorio_x_Trafos 
        { CodigoDelfos = transformador.Codigo_delfos, Revision = transformador.Revision, Cantidad = 1, CodigoAccesorio = "05-CBPA0150000802000P0800"},
    new Accesorio_x_Trafos
        { CodigoDelfos = transformador.Codigo_delfos, Revision = transformador.Revision, Cantidad = 2, CodigoAccesorio = "05-CBPA0150000803150P0700"},
    new Accesorio_x_Trafos
        { CodigoDelfos = transformador.Codigo_delfos, Revision = transformador.Revision, Cantidad = 3, CodigoAccesorio = "05-CBPA0150000803150P0700"}
};
//Guardo
mContext.SaveChanges();
```

Lo cual dispara la siguiente excepción:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while...

Y al ver la InnerException, hace referencia a un problema de FK

> Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY
>   \"FK_dbo.Accesorio_x_Trafos_dbo.StepUps_CodigoDelfos_Revision\". El
>   conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos \"DBTrafos\", tabla
>   \"dbo.StepUps\".\r\nSe terminó la instrucción.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar mi problema?

O si es el caso, como puedo obtener mayor detalle de cual es específicamente el conflicto con la llave foránea?

Gracias!!

Comment: Revisa que con el new() no estés quitando de Accesorio_x_Trafos un registro que este relacionado con StepUps

Comment: @J4ime Hola! ¿con el new LIst<...? En la tabla Accesorio_x_Trafos no existe ningún registro en este momento, porque al intentar hacer el insert produce el error que mencioné arriba

Comment: Pues entonces o bien la relación en la BBDD o la relación en el context del código está mal, porque por lo que entiendo del error es que estás intentando insertar en la tabla Accesorio_x_Trafos un registro con una clave que no existe en StepUps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que tu error esta en el mapeo de la clase a base de datos. La propiedad que hace de clave foránea debe especificarse con la etiqueta de Entity Framework `[ForeignKey(name)]` , quedando de la siguiente forma :

```
public class Accesorio_x_Trafos
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string CodigoAccesorio { get; set; }        

    [ForeignKey("Transformador")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }       
    public int? Cantidad { get; set; }    
}
```

Realmente no se si es posible que sea clave foránea de dos atributos diferentes de tablas diferentes. Aunque podría resolverse haciendo una generalización de las tablas Transformador y StepUp. O puesto que ambos tienen los mismos campos del mismo tipo dejar solo una tabla añadiendo un campo que especifique el tipo (Transformador o StepUp). Te dejo un link donde poder ver el uso de la etiqueta [ForeignKey](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Revisando algo mas tu caso, veo que el error que comentas , se menciona en la pagina de micrsoft [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1) en la seccion :Agregar una migración.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Generalizando las tablas y añadiendo un tipo para diferenciarlas , quedaría asi :

```
public class Generica 
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Codigo_delfos { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Accesorio_x_Trafos> Accesorio_x_Trafos { get; set; }
    public int Tipo; (1= Transformador, 24 = StepUp)
    //Muchas otras propiedades.. !!!!Que sean comunes, sino deberan ir en tablas separadas haciendo relacion a la PK Codigo_delfos¡¡¡¡
}
```

Te dejo otro link con una explicacion y ejemplos simples de la generalización en el modelo entidad-relación [link](https://virtual.itca.edu.sv/Mediadores/dbd/u1/13_modelo_entidad_relacin_extendida.html)

Comment: Hola, gracias por tomarte el tiempo! Por un lado hay que tener en cuenta que la clave es compuesta, por el otro, necesito que esta tabla almacene objetos relacionados tanto a Transformador como a StepUp :(

Comment: Hola Juan, de nada. Te comentaba lo de generalizar las tablas. Porque pensándolo mejor, no es posible que una foreign key apunte a primary key de tablas diferentes. Puesto que al insertar un dato, no sabria en que tabla comprobar si esa foreign key es correcta

Comment: y cómo suele resolverse este tipo de situaciones? en caso de que dos tablas puedan tener relación con el mismo tipo de objeto?

Comment: La solución es lo que en orientacion a objetos seria la herencia. Una generalización. Se puede realizar de diversas formas (implementaciones). Puedes sacar los atributos comunes de las tablas (transformador y stepup) en una (que seria la que se relaciona con accesorios) y los atributos especificos de cada tipo, en dos tablas diferentes, relacionadas con la clave de la primera tabla (donde estan los datos comunes).

Comment: Puesto que en tu caso no hay atributos especificos , sino que ambas tablas stepup y transformador tienen los mismos atributos. Optaria por dejar una sola tabla cambiar el nombre a uno mas generico y añadir una propiedad tipo, pudiendo ser, un entero un caracter o booleano dependiendo que lo requieras o puedas requerir en un futuro. Para poder diferenciar si se trata de stepup o transformador

Answer (score 1):

Terminé solucionándolo con un poco de ayuda de los comentarios de Alexmaister.

Lo hice creando una clase abstracta que remplazó `Accesorio_x_Trafos` de tal manera, que luego, especifique cada clase heredada con su llave foránea y propiedad de navegación correspondiente.

```
public abstract class AccesorioTransformador
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CodigoAccesorio { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }   
}

public class AccesorioStepUp : AccesorioTransformador
{
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }   
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CodigoDelfos)+","+nameof(Revision))]   
    public StepUp.StepUp Transformador { get; set; }
}

public class AccesorioDistribucion : AccesorioTransformador
{
    public string CodigoDelfos { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }           
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CodigoDelfos) + "," + nameof(Revision))]
    public Transformador Transformador { get; set; }
}
```

De esta manera, en cada una de las correspondientes clases, utilicé propiedades, ya sea de tipo `ICollection<AccesorioStepUp>` como `ICollection<AccesorioDistribucion>`.